# Handling different screen resolutions in blackberry with single image

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have one PNG image and am applying it to all the screens as background. Its resolution is 360x480 because I started programming for 9800 simulator. I am developing for OS 6.0. When I test my app for 9700 simulator having screen resolution 480x360, the image covers only half the screen. I have researched and learnt about using Fixed32 and scale and I have applied it as well. But still the background seems to cause an issue. I have only one image in resource folder. How to handle this one image to apply suitably for all different blackberry devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to resize the image based to screen width and height to fit to the screen you are are running.

For this the following methods will use.

```
public static EncodedImage sizeImage(EncodedImage image, int width, 
              int height) {
              EncodedImage result = null;

              int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getWidth());
              int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getHeight());

              int requiredWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(width);
              int requiredHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(height);

              int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32,
                requiredWidthFixed32);
              int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32,
                requiredHeightFixed32);

              result = image.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);
              return result;
             }
```

After resizeing  use below method for cropping.

```
public static Bitmap cropBitmap(Bitmap original, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

         int x = (original.getWidth() / 2) - (width / 2); // Center the new size by width
        int y = (original.getHeight() / 2) - (height / 2); // Center the new size by height
        int[] argb = new int[width * height]; 
        original.getARGB(argb, 0, width, x, y, width, height);
        bmp.setARGB(argb, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return bmp;
```

Create bitmap image as follow.

```
 EncodedImage  eImage = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/new.png" );
 EncodedImage bitimage=sizeImage(eImage,Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());

 Bitmap image=cropBitmap(bitimage.getBitmap(),Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
```

pass above bitmap to you manager.

Now set the returned bitmap as background to screen.It worked for me.Hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Koti. I am currently using getMainManager().setBackground(
                BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(
                Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bgplain.png"))); 
for adding image to background. I have added your code in my program. Is there any pre-requisite that is necessary to make this work? I substituted Bitmap.getBitmapResource(bmp)....but its throwing me an error. Could you kindly suggest me as to how do i access the returned bitmap value?

Comment: I understood about passing the bitmap to manager....but with your above code, will I be sending eImage, bitimage, image or bmp?? With your last answer, I assume I must pass bmp...but how do I relate it with other image objects that you create?

Comment: In cropbitmap function, you have used first parameter as Bitmap and in Bitmap image = cropBitmap(...) You are passing object of EncodedImage. Its throwing an error there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3743/discussion-between-koti-and-rashmi-b)

Comment: Bitmap image=cropBitmap(bitimage,Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
When I use the above code, it says "Change method 'cropBitmap(Bitmap,int,int) to cropBitmap(EncodedImage,int,int)

Comment: Bitmap  _bmap=bitimage.getBitmap(); add this code before calling croping function

Answer (score 0):

To set your image with required width and height use Bitmap scale; And if you want to put your image as Background then put the bitmap image to VerticalFieldManager like this:
For all devices it works:

```
Bitmap bit=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png");
Bitmap scalingBitmap=new Bitmap(Device.getWidth(),Device.getHeight());  //here you can give any size.Then it sets the image according to your required width and height;
bit.scaleInto(scalingBitmap, Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS);  //This is important;
VerticalFieldManager mainVertical=new VerticalFieldManager()
{
     //Here Device.getWidth() and Device.getHeight(); These two are your Blackberry Device width and height;(According your 9800 it takes 480x360)
    protected void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        g.clear();
        g.drawBitmap(0, 0, Device.getWidth(),Device.getHeight(), scalingBitmap, 0, 0); 
        super.paint(g);
    }
    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) 
    {               
        super.sublayout(Device.getWidth(),Device.getHeight());
        setExtent(Device.getWidth(),Device.getHeight());
    }
};
add(mainVertical);
```

This is enough.